# angular js gender dropdown with default null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know much about angular since I am still learning. I got this issue with a dropdown gender and I want to add a --Select-- but it duplicates.

Here is my code:

```
   <td style="font-family: Brandon-Grotesque, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 25px;">
   <select name="gender"  ng-model="formData.gender" ng-options="option.name for option in formData.availableOptions track by option.id"></select>
   </td>
```

and here is the angular code:

```
       //var app = angular.module('formApp',['ngMaterial']);
      var app = angular.module('formApp',[]);
      app.controller('formController',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializer){

          $scope.formData = {
                availableOptions: [
                    {id:"",name:"--Select--"},
                    {id:"male",name:"Male"},
                    {id:"female",name:"Female"}
                ],
                gender:{id:"",name:"--Select--"}
          };

      });


</script>
```

Comment: from [AJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) it states  _a single hard-coded <option> element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the <select> element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option._

Comment: What do you mean by 'it duplicates'? From what I can tell nothing here duplicates. Here's a plnkr which is based on what you provided http://plnkr.co/edit/HmTBuHUZVGp5IOYhQCbH?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can replace your HTML code

```
<select name="gender"  ng-model="formData.gender" ng-options="option.name for option in formData.availableOptions track by option.id"></select>
```

with

```
 <select name="gender"  ng-model="formData.gender" ng-options="option.name for option in formData.availableOptions track by option.id">
     <option value="">---Please select---</option>

   </select>
```

and JS code

```
$scope.formData = {
                availableOptions: [
                    {id:"",name:"--Select--"},
                    {id:"male",name:"Male"},
                    {id:"female",name:"Female"}
                ],
                gender:{id:"",name:"--Select--"}
          };
```

with

```
$scope.formData = {
                availableOptions: [
                    {id:"male",name:"Male"},
                    {id:"female",name:"Female"}
                ],
                gender:null
          };
```

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate your very brief and understandable code fix.

Comment: Hi Liu, if t worked, please accept it as answer and upvote it. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: I think you already done it by accepting the answer(by marking it with a green tick). Thanks!